# MongoDB - Update field in nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-update

This is my collection structure in MongoDB:

```
{
  _id: id,
  name: name,
  loans: [
    [{id: 1, acName: "ABC"}],
    [{id: 2, acName: "DEF"}],
    [{id: 3, acName: "GHI"}]
  ]
}
```

How can I update `acName` of a specific ID? Let's say, I want to update `acName` of `id` 2. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1: Without arrayFilters**

1. Use `$elemMatch` to find the existence of `id: 2` in nested arrays.
2. With all positional operator (`$[]`) to update the respective document field.

```
db.collection.update({
  "loans": {
    $elemMatch: {
      $elemMatch: {
        id: 2
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  $set: {
    "loans.$.$[].acName": "<NEW VALUE>"
  }
})
```

[Demo Solution 1 @ MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7GSs42NvcTs)

---

**Solution 2: With arrayFilters**

1. Use `$elemMatch` to find the existence of id: 2 in nested arrays.
2. With filtered positional operator (`$[<identifier>]`) and arrayFilters to update the respective document field.

```
db.collection.update({
  "loans": {
    $elemMatch: {
      $elemMatch: {
        id: 2
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  $set: {
    "loans.$.$[loan].acName": "<NEW VALUE>"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "loan.id": 2
    }
  ]
})
```

[Demo Solution 2 @ MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w9Tya2vEUEF)

Comment: Great. Thanks. It works. Could you please do me another favor? Let's say, my loans is like this:  loans: [
    [{id: 1, acName: "ABC"}, {id: 4, acName: "KKK}],
    [{id: 2, acName: "DEF"}, {id: 5}, acName: "MMM"],
    [{id: 3, acName: "GHI", {id: 6, acName: "NNN"}}]
  ]   How would I be able to change acname of id 2 ?

Comment: Solution 2 is preferred based on your new data. [Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/z_33yTOrEGl)

Comment: It worked as well. Highly appreciated. Please please don't mind. What if I need to update all acName together depnding on category?  loans: [ [{id: 1, acName: "ABC", category: "good"}, {id: 4, acName: "KKK", category: "bad"}], [{id: 2, acName: "DEF", category: "good"}, {id: 5, acName: "MMM", category: "good"}], [{id: 3, acName: "GHI", category: "bad"}, {id: 6, acName: "NNN", category: "bad"}}] ]  I will not ask question again. I apologize for repetitive questions.

Comment: You may look for this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TZz_L_GO375). While would suggest try to attempt before asking. And would recommend to create a new question for the new requirement. Thanks.